# Advanced ViewHolder (with listeners and additional logic)

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

A classic `ViewHolder` is something like

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageButton btnEdit;
    public ImageButton btnDelete;
    public ImageButton btnCancel;
    public ImageButton btnAccept;
    public TextView txtLbTagName;
    public EditText txtEdTagName;
    public ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
}
```

I want to enhance it:

1.store `onClickListener`'s for my buttons in it (which might just switch my ViewSwitcher, or perform any operations on EditText, or update value in database)

2.have a method in my `ViewHolder` to do something like

```
public void attach(Tag tag) {
    //assign value to my TextView, attach listeners if needed etc.
}
```

1. Will this work?
2. Will performance be lower compared to classic ViewHolder?
3. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, it is good, just because of you are saving time and not duplicating the code. There is no difference where you call methods from.

Comment: 1. yes 2. no 3. yep, just for the neatness alone.